# Rails 4 Capybara how to test the exact order of the input fields in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec-rails

In my Rails 4 app, I have a form for the user to set a new password.
I want to test this with Capybara and test the order of the input fields as I need to be sure they are always in a certain order in the UI.

in my UI I have:

```
input[@id = "user_current_password"]
input[@id = "user_password"]
input[@id = "user_password_confirmation"]
```

My test, for now, looks like:

```
it 'changing the expired password' do

    render

    expect(rendered).to have_content("Update Password")
    expect(rendered).to have_content("Current Password:")
    expect(rendered).to have_content("New Password:")
    expect(rendered).to have_content("Confirm New Password:")
    expect_submit_button("Change Password")

    # Boxes order
    current_password = page.has_xpath?('//input[@id = "user_current_password"]')
    new_password = page.has_xpath?('//input[@id = "user_password"]')
    confirm_new_password = page.has_xpath?('//input[@id = "user_password_confirmation"]')

  end
```

I need to add a way to check the input fields are always in the same order. So if for some reason the order change I see the test fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rendered` in view specs is just a string containing the HTML so depending on exactly what the HTML looks like the simplest method would just be a regexp

```
rendered.match?(/id="user_current_password".+id="user_password".+id="user_password_confirmation"/m)
```

If you wanted to get more "correct" and actually verify structure you could potentially use `has_xpath?` using the `following-sibling` axis or possibly `has_css?` with an adjacent sibling selector (+), but to provide those queries we'd need to see the actual HTML.